# How to restrict lambda URL invocation to users redirected from custom domain name?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-route53

I have set up a CNAME record to redirect users that visit my custom domain name to my lambda function's lambda function URL. However, the CNAME record exposes the lambda function's lambda function URL to the public. How do I allow users redirected from the custom domain name to access the lambda function while blocking everybody else?

Answer (score 0):

Public DNS is just that - public. Trying to mask public information is not a good strategy.

A non-foolproof technique is to check the HTTP requesting **Host** header. If it matches your domain, go to the next step. If it matches the Lambda URL, return an error, drop the connect, etc. If the host is anything else drop the connection.

A better strategy is to implement some form of authorization.